# Overlay form when html5 canvas is double clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to overlay an html form when my html5 canvas is double clicked. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

```
canvas.ondblclick = myDblClick;

function myDblClick(e) {
    //Generate Overlay
}
```

Comment: have you tried it? what was the problem?

Comment: I actually don't know what to fill in for the comment, I'm kinda new to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to do it for you, but I am going to tell you where to start.

You must learn about creating HTML elements on the fly (ie `document.createElement('input')`) or else creating your form in a div and then hiding it.

On the double click you must unhide your form or create your elements, and then position them [absolutely](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) over the canvas.

Comment: Thanks, Simon. This should give me somewhere to start.